# awesomium web scraping certain parts

Tags: javascript, c#, scrape, awesomium

I asked this earlier but I wanted to rephrase the question. I am trying to make a scraper for my project. I would like to have it display a certain part of a link. The only part of the link that changes is the number. This number is what I would like to scrape. The link looks like this:

```
<a href="/link/player.jsp?user=966354" target="_parent" "="">
```

As mentioned I am trying to scrap only the 966354 part of the link. I have tried several ways to do this but cant figure it out. When I add

```
 <a href="/link/player.jsp?user="
```

to the code below it breaks

```
 List<string> player = new List<string>();
 string html = webControl2.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML");
 MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, "<a href=\\s*(.+?)\\s*</a>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
 foreach (Match m in m1)
 {
    string players = m.Groups[1].Value;
    player.Add(players);
 }
    listBox.DataSource = player;
```

So I removed it, it shows no errors until I go to run the program then I get this error:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Awesomium.Windows.Forms.dll"

So I tried this and it some what works:

```
string html = webControl2.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML");
```

This code scraps but not the way I would like, Could someone lend a helping hand please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (install it via NuGet) and XPath queries to parse HTML.

Something like this:

```
string html = webControl2.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML");
var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

var playerIds = new List<string>();

var playerNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href, '/link/profile-view.jsp?user=')]");

if (playerNodes != null)
{
    foreach (var playerNode in playerNodes)
    {
        string href = playerNode.Attributes["href"].Value;

        var parts = href.Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (parts.Length > 1)
        {
            playerIds.Add(parts[1]);
        }
    }

    id.DataSource = playerIds;
}
```

Also you may find these two simple helper classes useful: https://gist.github.com/AlexP11223/8286153

The first one is [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for WebView/WebControl and the second one has some static methods to generate JS code for retrieving elements (JSObject) by XPath + getting coordinates of JSObject)

Comment: Edit, it just crashed with an error: NullReferenceException was unhandled pointing to foreach

Comment: playerNodes will be null if there is no suitable elements. So you may want to check it, if you sometimes execute it on pages without these elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using a sample html file such as below, I was unable to duplicate the exception.

```
<html>
<a href="/link/player.jsp?user=966354" target="_parent" "="">test</a>
</html>
```

However, the javascript

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML
```

will return "test" in my example. What you probably want is

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href
```

which will return the href portion.

The 'innerHTML' property will return everything between the start and end tags (such as <html> </html>). This is probably the reason you have better success when getting the 'html' element - you end up parsing the entire <a> </a> link.

FYI, as a test you can use your browser to test out the javascript output.

Comment: I had already tried that one also. It pulls the link but the wrong one also pulls the entire link, which I don't want. the only part I wanna scrape is the numbers "966354" not the entire link. But thank you for your reply.

Comment: Well, you will need to identify the link from the other links in the page somehow (ideally by ID, but that doesn't seem to be available in your example, so perhaps by the presence of the 'target="_parent"' attribute.

After the correct link is obtained, it is a simple matter of regex to parse out the bit after the 'user=' part of the link.